# Reverse for 'filter_display' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'continent': 'America'}' not found

Tags: django, url, view

I have "oReverseMatch at /filter" error while running my app?
This is urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myform.views',
                       url(r'^contact$', 'contact'),
                       url(r'^affiche$', 'affiche'),
                       url(r'^add$', 'add'),
                       url(r'^filter$', 'filter'),
                       url(r'^filter_display/(?P<continent>[-\w]+)/$', 'filter_display',name='FilterDisplay'),
```

This is my view.py:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    Continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_continent())   
    Country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_country())
    City = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_city())
    Server_Adress = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_adress())

def filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                 
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)                                                                                                                                            
        if form.is_valid() :
            Continent = form.cleaned_data['Continent']
            Country = form.cleaned_data['Country']
            City = form.cleaned_data['City']
            Server_Adress = form.cleaned_data['Server_Adress']
            #Continent = dict(form1.fields['Continent'].choices)[Continent]
            #Country = dict(form1.fields['Country'].choices)[Country]
            #City = dict(form1.fields['City'].choices)[City]
            #Server_Adress = dict(form1.fields['Server_Adress'].choices)[Server_Adress]
            url = reverse('filter_display', args=(),   kwargs={'continent': 'America',})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = FilterForm()
    return render_to_response('filter.html', { 'form': form }, RequestContext(request))     


def filter_display(request, continent):
        if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                 
            form1 = FilterForm(request.POST)                                                                                                                                            
            if form1.is_valid() :
                Continent = form1.cleaned_data['Continent']
                Country = form1.cleaned_data['Country']
                City = form1.cleaned_data['City']
                Server_Adress = form1.cleaned_data['Server_Adress']
        else:
            form1 = FilterForm()
        data = Select_WHERE(continent)
        return render_to_response('affiche_continent.html', {'form1':form1, 'data':data }, RequestContext(request))
```

It works when I type 'localhost:8000/filter_display/EUROPE/' in URL.
The code works perfectly in "filter_display".
But when I try to pass parameter using the "filter" function in view I get this error

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pass parameter using the filter function): What code threw that error? Can you show the traceback?

Comment: using HttpResponse Redirect in filter view i'm passing parameter(continent) in the url

Comment: Try removing the `args` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You have supplied a `name` for that URL, so you should use that in the call to `reverse`:

```
url = reverse('FilterDisplay', kwargs={'continent': 'America',})
```